Powershell Wait-Job does not return reliably
from a Jenkins Pipeline we call a powershell script that calls a tool to execute some tests. We want the pipeline to wait for the test execution being finished. As a fallback in case of any issues we define a maximum test execution time as a timeout for the job. Usually this works fine. In some occassions, however, the Wait-Job does not return before the timeout, although we can see on the VM where the process is executed, that the tool process exited. All test results are there, no exceptions visible. We have a clean test run but the job seems to be hanging somehow.
That's part of the script we use:
$code = {
        param($toolPath,$configfile,$workdir)

        & $toolPath -ConfigurationFile $configfile
        $ExitCodeInScript=$LASTEXITCODE
        return $ExitCodeInScript
    }

$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -ArgumentList "$Path","$configurationfile","$WorkDir"
    if (Wait-Job $j -Timeout $TimeoutSeconds) {
        # If we return safely, we analyse the return value of the script block here
# not so relevant in detail because we never get here in case of the error
        $jobOutput = Receive-Job $j
    } else {
        # Timeout hit. We set our own exit code`
        # This is where we always land if the process does not return
}

We use Powershell v5.1
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3031

Checked the processes on the VM and found that the test tool has exited and results are complete
We could see some powershell processes still active, we could not relate to what is executed there
Checked windows eventlog and couldn't see any issues

Any ideas how we can go on analyzing this issue? I cannot see a clear pattern. It happens in different pipelines on different agents.
Is there any approach to make this more reliable or even a completely different way of implementing a call tool, wait for exit in powershell?

I think you are hanging because some lines of output do not end in a return so foreach ($line in $jobOutput) doesn't return.  It may be the some outputs need to be flush() so the return can be seen.

just updated the question to make it easier to focus on the part having the issue. @jdweng in case of the issue we never get into the if-branch

There is no $TimeoutSeconds defined in this example. Is the same true in your script? Perhaps you're not actually giving it a timeout value

Are you getting an exception.  Add a try/catch.  Is $j null?

Note that each background job runs in its own powershell.exe child process, so at least hypothetically the problem could be that such a child process doesn't exit - though the code you're showing wouldn't explain that. As a generally preferable, lightweight alternative, you could use a thread job to see if that makes a difference: Use the Start-ThreadJob cmdlet, which in Windows PowerShell can be installed on demand with, e.g., Install-Module ThreadJob -Scope CurrentUser.

@DougMaurer i just left out the timeout definition here. As said the timeout side (else branch) works fine.

@mklement0 thanks for the idea. I'll check out the Start-ThreadJob.
